# Save MongoDB Database Object on Modify

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a number of Objects I've created that I use Globally in my Application. I would like them to be saved when a Property under them is modified.

Would something like this work? Wouldn't this only save it if I was actually setting a new value of Campaign, not accessing something under it like Campaign.Name?

```
public Campaign Campaign
{
    get { return _campaign; }
    set { SaveCampaign(value); }
}
private static void SaveCampaign(Campaign campaign)
{
    var databaseClient = new MongoClient(TerminusService.DatabaseConnectionString);
    var server = databaseClient.GetServer();
    var database = server.GetDatabase("TerminusDialer");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Campaign>("campaigns");
    collection.Save(campaign);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will only save if you're setting a new value to `Campaign`, and not changing its name.

I have a suggestion you could try:

1. You could create an event which fires whenever a property from that class changes. Here's a compact example: [Watch it working on .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cKe8C0)

   ```
   class ListenToMe
   {
       public event EventHandler OnPropertyChanged;

       private string _name;
       public string Name
       {
           get{return _name;}
           set
           {
               if (_name!=value)
               {
                   this._name = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged(this,new EventArgs());
               }
           }
       }
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
       ListenToMe someone = new ListenToMe();
       someone.OnPropertyChanged += (o,e) => Console.WriteLine("My new name is: "+ someone.Name); // we will do something whenever props change
       someone.Name = "Mary"; // upon changing it, it appears on Console
       someone.Name = "Lucy";
       someone.Name = "Angelica";
   }
   ```

You'll see a lot of information about this kind of approach if you look around for the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which is largely used to bind UI elements to the view model (and for other things as well).

You could also just call a method from each `set` for each property of the class, but then you'd have to call the method from `Campaign`, which might be undesirable. That's why publishing an event seem nicer in these circunstances.

**Note**: Also, as a word of advice, be careful when doing this kind of thing. I believe you're doing this to "auto-save" information at each step, and it seems interesting, but you may end up making lots of roundtrips to your database during certain operations if you forget that each property set will cause a db update side-effect.

Comment: Thank you for that very thorough response. That is indeed what I am attempting to accomplish. I have data in memory in a RESTful WCF Service. I need to be able to auto-save the data that is modified by the REST POSTs. I do believe I will attempt this method, thank you!

Comment: @Smarter Ok :), just let us know if everything went out ok. And if possible, accept the answer after you verify that it solves your problem. Thanks.